# get the record from which a record is cloned

Tags: clone

I want to get the details of the record from which I cloned.

I tried using getCloneSourceId(), but it gives me the parent record data. I tried the following but didn't work for me.

I cloned record B from A, C from B and D from C.

Now when i check in my trigger using getCloneSourceId() on all B,C,D records, I get A data only.

But I am looking for A on B, B on C and C on D.

Please let me know if there is anyway for doing it.

Comment: Try adding DML inserts between the clone operations...

Comment: Hey Phil, I updated the questions. This is with data I already have in the system. I want what their immediate clone parent was.

Comment: Hi, is it a custom clone or standard clone functionality?

Comment: standard clone from SF UI

Comment: The clone source is not persisted unless you specifically add it as a custom field on your object. So if this is already existing data, you can't do what you want. With new data, going forward with the custom field, you can do what you like (assuming you have a trigger that detects the cloning and stores the source ID in that custom field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected documented behavior for [`getCloneSourceId()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm), refer to the excerpt below.

> If A is cloned to B, B is cloned to C, and C is cloned to D, then B, C, and D **all point back to A as their clone source**.

If you want to track the parent's id, you will need to introduce a custom field and populate that with the `Id` of the record from which you are cloning on the cloned record.